# I want to combine these two triggers in to single trigger .how to do that

Tags: sql-server

Trigger 1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_IM_ServiceRequest_Hx] ON [dbo].[IM_ServiceRequest] AFTER INSERT
AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO  IM_ServiceRequest_Hx
SELECT * FROM INSERTED


PRINT 'AFTER INSERT Trigger fired.'
END
```

Trigger 2:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_IM_ServiceRequest] ON [dbo].[IM_ServiceRequest] FOR UPDATE
AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO IM_ServiceRequest_Hx

SELECT * FROM DELETED

PRINT 'FOR UPDATE Trigger fired.'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You could combine them by specifying multiple actions separated by commas in the `CREATE TRIGGER` declaration. Then, use appropriate conditional filters to decide how to update your audit table, something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[INSERT_UPDATE_IM_ServiceRequest_Hx] ON [dbo].[IM_ServiceRequest] FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

BEGIN

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  IM_ServiceRequest_Hx
    SELECT * FROM INSERTED

    PRINT 'AFTER INSERT Trigger fired.'
    END


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INSERTED) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM DELETED)
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  IM_ServiceRequest_Hx
    SELECT * FROM DELETED

    PRINT 'FOR UPDATE Trigger fired.'
    END

END
```

Comment: Of course, this is subtly different from the original triggers in the case of a 0 row `INSERT` or `UPDATE`. The original triggers will still `PRINT` messages but this trigger will not. Probably doesn't matter, but worth highlighting.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I did suspect that the merge wouldn't be entirely faithful to OP's original code, but couldn't pinpoint it. Could you help me improve this answer? I'd really appreciate that :)